# Rodar arquivos locais dentro de um frame em um modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp

Tenho esse código, uma função asp:

```
sub montaContrato()
    %>
    <!--<div id="dialog1" title="Diálogo Modal" hidden="hidden">Este é um teste de Dialogo Modal usando JQuery-UI</div>-->
    <iframe id="dialog" class="ui-helper-hidden"></iframe>
    <tr>
        <td class="label_right" nowrap>Contrato&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="num_contrato" value="" size="15" maxlength="17" tabindex="1" OnKeyPress="javascript:MascAlfaNum()" OnKeyDown="TeclaEnter()" onchange="PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();">
            <!--<img id='' style='display:; cursor:hand' name='Pesquisa_Contrato' width='16' height='16' src='/gen/mid/lupa.gif' border='0' alt='Pesquisa Contrato' onClick="javascript:AbrePesquisa('/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp?ind_situacao=&tipo_empresa=&ind_classificacao=&p_cod_tipo_contrato=&indsubmit=false&txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&ind_tipo_pessoa=J&funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&abre_modal=S&ind_alteracao_contrato=&tipo_preco=','Pesquisa_Contrato','Pesquisa Contrato', 700, 500, 20, 15, 'S')">-->
            <img id='btnLupa' style='display:; cursor:hand' name='Pesquisa_Contrato' width='16' height='16' src='/gen/mid/lupa.gif' border='0' alt='Pesquisa Contrato' onclick='AbrirModal("http://www.javascriptkit.com", "Javascript Kit", 480, 360)'>
            <input type="text"  name="nome_contrato" value="" size="50" tabindex="-1" Readonly class="camposblocks">
            <input type="hidden" name="cod_ts_contrato" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ind_tipo_pessoa" value="J" />
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <%
end sub
```

Esse código é montado nessa `<table>`:

```
<body>
<%AbreTable()%>
<font class="subtitulos"><%=txt_subtitulo%></font>
<%FechaTable()%>
<form method="post" name="form01">    
<%AbreTable()%>
<div id="txt_msg" class="msg" align="center"><%=txt_msg%></div>


<table border="0" width="100%">
    <%
    montaOpSucInspetoria()
    montaContrato()
    if txt_modulo = "40" then
        montaNumBeneficiario()
    end if 
    montaNumAtendimento("S")           
    montaDataAtendimento()
    montaUsuarioAtendimento()
    montaCboMotivoAtd()
    montaCboSituacao()
    %>
</table>
```

A função montaContrato() é que monta essa `<tr>`. O que está acontecendo. Na chamada do botão `btnLupa`, que é uma imagem(gif), se eu coloco nessa chamada uma URL do tipo: `http://www.minha_pagina.com.br`, funciona muito bem. Porem se eu coloco uma página que está no diretório do projeto, na forma passada acima `/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp?...`, não funciona. Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me dar uma luz a respeito.

Comment: Olá, tente utilizar tag <head><base href="http://www.seudominio.com.br" /></head> [ https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base ]